# Internal linking in dynamic content without page reload in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am building simple blog with Angular 5, and I have problem with internal linking.
One of the compponents is PostComponent, it fetches post content from backend and displays it. The problem is that post can have internal links like:

```
<a href="/posts/another-post">
```

Such links cause complete page reload and since I use Angular I would like to avoid that. I've tried to change anchors to something like that:

```
<a routerLink="/posts/another-post">
```

but it also does not work, probably because html was not processed by Angular since it is just text binded to paragraph like:

```
<p [safeHtml]="(post$ | async)?.content"></p>
```

What is the easiest way to achieve internal linking without page reload in dynamically loaded content in AngularX?

Comment: Don't know the actual syntax, doesn't `<a [routerLink] = "['/posts/another-post']" routerLinkActive='active'>` work?

Comment: unfortunatelly such link does not work, because it is not compiled by angular. It works only if this is part of static component but not dynamically injected content via [safeHtml]

Answer (score 1):

You can't user routerLink directive like this as the dynamic HTML content is not parsed by Angular. You can do one of the following:

1. **Create a dynamic component**, the HTML you need to display will be rendered as an Angular component. Docs: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
2. **Parse the rendered DOM** after each change of content, search for relative links and link the click event to Router.navigate
3. **Use Custom elements** - define a custom element for internal links (e. g. `<a-internal href="/posts/another-post">Another post</a>`. The element will be parsed by browser and linked to a defined component, which will use Router.navigate on click. Docs: https://angular.io/guide/elements

I personally would choose:

1. If my HTML content should actually work as a component and editors of such content are Angular developers
2. If the only concern is internal links and I am sure I will not need any other active content
3. If I will need to implement more magic in my HTML content (e. g. widgets, buttons)

Number 3 also feels like the most "Angular way" to me.